# Run copied file in container

Tags: docker

I would like copy file from host to container then execute it. Like this:

```
docker run --name ubuntu_trusty ubuntu:14.04
docker cp ./script.sh ubuntu_trusty:/script.sh
# run ubuntu_trusty container then execute /bin/bash /script.sh
```

I can see the ubuntu_trusty container

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
20e54389340e        ubuntu:14.04        "/bin/bash"         9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 1 seconds ago                       ubuntu_trusty
```

But i don't know how to "re-run" my "/bin/bash /script.sh" in it. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To complete kev answer as fully working answer, container must be running when use `docker exec`, so we must `run` container and keep it alive with **-d**:

```
docker run -i -d --name ubuntu_trusty ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

Then we can `cp` and `exec`

```
docker cp script.sh ubuntu_trusty:/script.sh
docker exec ubuntu_trusty /bin/bash /script.sh
Hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [docker exec](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) like this:

### interactive

```
$ docker exec -it ubuntu_trusty bash
>>> /script.sh
>>> exit
```

### non-interactive

```
$ docker exec ubuntu_trusty bash /script.sh
```

Comment: Hi, i got ``Error response from daemon: Container ubuntu_trusty is not running`` when ``docker exec ubuntu_trusty bash /script.sh``.

Comment: @bux `docker exec` only works on a running container.